# How to migrate products between catalogs in IBM Bluemix API Connect?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

How do we migrate Products from one catalog to another in IBM API Connect?

We publish API's to dev catalog and once we are done developing ,they need to be moved to test catalog.

Comment: Welcome visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so we can give you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the apic command line toolkit to do that.

There are examples of different scenarios in the readme page here: https://github.com/ibm-apiconnect/cli

e.g. to clone all the apis in a given catalog:
apic apis:clone